# Enum returned in the web api response is wrapped around extra quotes

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am using the global serializer of `System.Text.Json.Serialization` like this`options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());` in my startup file to have the enum return as string value instead of the index value. And have couple of controller action methods to check how the serilizer is working.

```
public enum TestEnum
{
    Value1,
    Value111
}

public IActionResult GetEnum()
{
    return Ok(TestEnum.Value1);
}
```

Now if get the response of the `GetEnum()` (see below) it gives me the response as ""Value1""

```
public async Task GETEnumValue()
{
    // my client generation code
    var result = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
    var stringResponse = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;        
}
```

No clue why the extra quotes are being attached here for `stringResponse = ""Value1""` If I return a c# model which has this enum as one of the property then I don't see the extra quotes.
Any leads here ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summary:** You serialize your string to JSON, but you never **de**serialize it.

This is what happens in detail:

1. You start with a string `Value1`.
2. Then you JSON-encode this string, leading to `"Value1"` (these double quotes look like C# double quotes, but they are JSON double quotes).
3. Then you read the result **as a string** (`ReadAsStringAsync`) instead of as JSON. Thus, you get a string containing a JSON string literal.

You can fix this by reading your JSON result **as JSON**...

```
var stringResponse = result.Content.ReadAsJsonAsync<string>().Result;
```

...(or by manually deserializing your result.)

Comment: Alternately, send `new ContentResult{Content = TestEnum.Value1.ToString()}` in the first place

Comment: Thanks @Heinzi , I wanted to avoid the deserialisation and thought that the response can be read as a string but your 2nd point makes more sense. Thanks again
Charlieface I hope you meant passing this content as part of the response,  if so then by using .ToString() I don't have to use the global serialisation. And I don't want to do this .ToString() in all places